# Path based authorization in Subversion

Tags: svn, path, authorization

am pretty much new to SVN, i need help with path based authorization. I have created several folders and i want a particular user to access only one folder. He should not be able to read or see other folders. And one particular user should be able to see all the stuff. Its like a folder is allotted to one user, only he can read and write. And one super user who is able to read all the folders in the SVN.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too broad and is answered in documentation. At first, you should read [SVNBook | Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) section.